# Why in many programming languages, the "continue" in loop statement isn't being called "next"

Tags: language-design

Why in many programming languages, the "continue" in loop statement isn't being called "next", but being called "continue"

"continue" makes no sense at all, doesn't match its actual functionality. In fact, it discontinues the current loop iteration.

Comment: The "continue" statement reevaluates the loop condition, thus continuing (or not) into its execution cycle. But, really, taxonomy is not math and we can't know for sure -- unless we ask whoever took the design decision:)

Comment: That would be Dennis Ritchie http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie

Comment: If it was called 'next' we would have questions here asking why it isn't 'continue'. The question is entirely pointless. The languages concerned aren't going to change as a result of this post.

Comment: It makes more sense compared with `break`, IMO. `break` breaks the loop; `continue` continues the loop, but not the current iteration. You can think of it as 'forget about the rest of the loop body, just keep going!'

Comment: @EJP, it isn't 'continue' because continue shouldn't skip anything. When you use continue it skips all the rest of the code of the current iteration

Comment: @Unreality When you use `next` it skips all the rest of the code of the current iteration too. I'm not fond of the phrase 'arguing over semantics' but that is exactly what you are doing. Your question is basically pointless: nobody is going to change it, and it is what it is. I suggest you get used to it.

Comment: ＠EJP I don't want to change it. I get used to it. I'm just curious. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is that `continue` comes from C (or even it's predecessors). Many languages are of the C family or at least influenced by C.

As for it not making sense, I never had any trouble with it. I didn't meat a programming language that used `next` before I met C (so your mileage may vary). As I see it, `continue` continues looping (and `break` discontinues looping).

Answer (score -1):

I agree with several posts that "continue" was inherited from C.  K&R were creating a modern programming language while keeping much of the efficiency and flexibility of assembly language.  I think from the assembly language perspective "continue" makes more sense than "next".  (Note: It has been several decades since I've even seen any assembly language code.)